# Handling error while saving managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have been working with an iOS app which has multiple context across multiple thread. Sometime the app while saving data encounters some data inconsistency error e.g sometimes a dangling pointer reference to some object so the app fills our `NSError` struct which i pass into

`[managedObjectContext save:&error]`

by default the app calls `abort()` to generate crash log and stuff. My question is what would be the proper way to handle this situation without calling `abort()` which crashes the app?
For example is there any way i can inform user that there was some error etc and the `managedObjectContext` rolls back it self etc?

Comment: Are you asking about this.. `if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }`

Comment: No. This would only log the crash info. I have that already. But i am asking to get the app out of this exception once it happens without crashing app.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to generate a report about the error and notify the user that something was wrong by means of an alert view (or similar). A simple can be found in [NSManagedObjectContext save error](http://matthewmorey.com/nsmanagedobjectcontext-save-error/).

If your run into another thread and you need to display UI stuff, grab the main thread first.

But now my question. What type of errors you receive? Is this the normal behavior? In my experience errors caused by saving the context should not appear in production, or at least, they should be analised.

Comment: Ok i am understanding your answer. the error occur due to some rare multithreading issue and some time some dangling pointer. I analyze then when i find logs but during runtime How can i get out of this error without calling abort().

Comment: @Umair follow the link I provided. If you don't call abort, nothing will happen and the execution will continue.

Comment: @Umair If possible, expand your answer telling about the architectures you use for managing threads and context together.

Comment: as you said excluding abort() will lead to continued execution, but if there is some inconsistency in managedObjectConxtext, Will calling "rollback" recover ?